# I have an error in http get request in swift 2

Tags: swift, http, get, request, alamofire

I have the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

With this Swift Code:

```
import Alamofire
let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://192.168.2.16/APIPruebas/validalogin/{\"usuario\":\"user\",\"pwd\":\"pwd\",\"id\":\"10\",\"ulogin\":\"1\",\"clogin\":\"1\"}")

print(request)
```

I think that the problem are the { }

But I don´t know if I escape " correctly with the \ character.

In postman works fine with this request

```
http://192.168.2.16/APIPruebas/validalogin/{"usuario":"user","pwd":"pwd","id":"10","ulogin":"1","clogin":"1"}
```

Which is the best metod to do a HTTP GET Request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to encode the url before using it with api like this

```
let str = "http://192.168.2.16/APIPruebas/validalogin/{\"usuario\":\"user\",\"pwd\":\"pwd\",\"id\":\"10\",\"ulogin\":\"1\",\"clogin\":\"1\"}"

let encodedUrl = str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Now pass encodedUrl in `Alamofire.request` method.

Comment: Welcome... Happy Coding :)